# Who is Erik Selvig referring to?

Tags: dialogue, marvel-cinematic-universe, reference, thor

Who are the two persons Erik Selvig is referring to in *Thor* (2011) in the scene where he is talking to Jane foster after SHIELD took their research.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The assumption by most, of course, is that the first one he was referring to was Bruce Banner. However, while no further mention is made of Erik's other colleague in the final film, [the original script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Thor.html) reveals the identity to be Dr. Pym (presumably Hank Pym, the original Ant-Man).

> **JANE**
>
> (TO DARCY)
>    Will you please stop talking about
>    your iPod?!
>
> (TO SELVIG)
>    Who are these people?
>
> **SELVIG**
>
> No one knows much about them. But
>    I knew a scientist -- a pioneer in
>    gamma radiation. SHIELD showed up,
>    and he was never heard from again.
>
> **JANE**
>
> I'm not going to let them do this.
>    I'm getting everything back.
>
> **SELVIG**
>
> **Please, let me contact one of my
>    colleagues. Dr. Pym has had some
>    dealings with these people.** I'll e-
>    mail him and see if he can help.
>
> **DARCY**
>
> They took your laptop, too.

Comment: You do know that he never said Dr. Pym
The Quote was.
Come on, please. Let me contact one of my colleagues. He's had some dealings with these people before. I'll e-mail him and maybe he can help>
End quote.
Time stamp 47m30s

Comment: @GodRatiyTheonetrueGodof He doesn't mention Dr. Pym *in the film itself*, but he *does* mention him in the original script. The answer explains that quite clearly.